# a zend framework routing question

Tags: zend-framework

i want to route my url `/resolution/index/res/1024x768` to `/resolution/1024x768`
the routing code in `application.ini` is:

```
resources.router.routes.resolution.route = '/resolution/:res/'
resources.router.routes.resolution.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route" 
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.controller = resolution
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.res=
```

the problem is that its working in my local computer but not in my host.
this url `mysite.com/resolution/index/res/1024x768` works but `/resolution/1024x768` doesnt. is there something more i need to do in production environment ?

i get the follow request parameters when accessing `/resolution/1024x768`:

```
Request Parameters:
array (
  'controller' => 'resolution',
  'action' => '1024x768',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

---

**Update**: as weird as it may sound, the first line in above routing code needed to be placed inside double quotes, like this:

```
resources.router.routes.resolution.route = "/resolution/:res/"
```

Comment: what are the request parameters for the same URL in localhost?

Comment: try changing your route to 'resolution/:res' (without the slashes)

Comment: @emaillenin tried that, doesnt work

Comment: Or at least without the leading slash.

Comment: actually none of my routes are working in my host, although all work fine in local computer :S

Comment: I tried your code locally, it works fine. It fails in production environment only when I put it under wrong section - [development : production] (i.e. in the bottom of application.ini).

Comment: @ischenkodv i have them at the top, inside `[production]`

Comment: any update guys ? this issue is making me mad !

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
resources.router.routes.resolution.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.resolution.route = '/resolution/(.*)'
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.controller = resolution
resources.router.routes.resolution.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.resolution.map.1 = "res"
```

**[Updated]**

Comment: tried this, produces an `Zend_Config_Exception` exception, must be something wrong with this code

Comment: Oh the type need to be "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"